# How to deal with short text data using NLP models?

Tags: nlp, bert

Now I want to use my own domain data to train NLP model like BERT. The following is the details of my data:

1. data length distribution: over 70% of my data has the length shorter than 5 and the largest length is 14;
2. data format: the data is a list of number representing the AS-PATH of BGP announcement.

I've tried to use HuggingFace transformer package to define BERT model and train, but the MLM loss is quite high. I think this is the cause of data length.

So I want to know that is there any way to deal with these short data?